# Uninstalling files deployed by merge module

Tags: installshield

I am working InstallShield 2015 project. Say for version 1 of my product is shipping some files using Merge module. Now I am working on version 5 of same product. During upgrade from v1 to v5, I want to remove files deployed by merge module from v1 and deploy new set of files from merge module in v5.

How can I achieve this? How should I remove files deployed by v1 merge module?

Answer (score 0):

***Merge Modules***: Merge modules are merged into your package at MSI compile time. They are intended to be merged into any MSI package that needs the components from the merge module. As such it is a distribution mechanism for shared components or runtimes or whatever you need that many packages consume.

***Merged Content***: The merge modules become part of the packages they are merged into and they are hence reference counted by MSI itself - not by some custom means - so that the components are only uninstalled when there are no other MSI packages depending on them. Components can also be set permanent, in which case they are never removed.

***Updates***: If you want to update the files from the merge module, you basically need to create a new version of the merge module.

Comment: You mean use same ISM file of merge module with same GUIDs and increased version number to replace existing package and deploy new one.

Comment: I haven't done so for years, but you would generally make a new version of the merge module with the new files in it. The merge module ends up as a binary msm file that can be included in other setup projects.